# Unknown column 'c63rd321' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I get form some users the following error: Unknown column 'c63rd321' in 'where clause' it works for one user but it doesn't for all other users any ideas?

```
$query = 'SELECT first_name,last_name,is_admin FROM '.$database.'.users WHERE users.id='.$user_id.' LIMIT 1';
```

do I need to add to users.id="" why does it work for one user and not for the others

Comment: have you done any sanitisation of `$database` or `$user_id`?

Comment: No the variables are set by calling $_SESSION['']

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `$user_id` is a string (`"c63fb321"`) and not an integer. Use quotes (and escape!)

```
$query = 'SELECT first_name,last_name,is_admin FROM '.$database.'.users WHERE users.id="'.mysql_real_escape_string($user_id).'" LIMIT 1';
```

(*Assuming the `mysql_` functions here, but this applies to PDO and mysqli as well*)

Comment: The user id is indeed a string and one that has several dash "-" chars,

Answer (score 1):

Please replace this:

```
$query = 'SELECT first_name,last_name,is_admin FROM '.$database.'.users WHERE users.id='.$user_id.' LIMIT 1';
```

... with this:

```
$query = 'SELECT first_name,last_name,is_admin FROM '.$database.'.users WHERE users.id=:user_id LIMIT 1';
                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

... and add `user_id` to the prepared statement parameters. If your library doesn't support prepared statements feel free to ask for further details but you should consider swithing to a better library.

Comment: User_id comes from $_SESSION['user']

Comment: @Dan - I can't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your user_id always integer? If so, you do not need to add quotes. but form your question I can guess that somehow it can be string. You may use `mysql_real_escape_string()` as quick measure (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

But, as you may know from previous answers, it would be much better if you rewrite it with mysqli or PDO. But it should be complex and perhaps will take some time.

Comment: I just went to the database and indeed the issue is that one of the users has id integer, all other users have a string has the id.